# glDrawElements not drawing

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing, render

I create my buffers with the following code:

```
//generate buffers
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
//glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_vertices);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_colors);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_normals);

// Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// Copy our vertices array in a buffer for OpenGL to use
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_vertices);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*3*vertices.size(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vTable.size() * sizeof(int), &vTable[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Position attribute
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0); //size = 3 (X,Y,Z)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


//Buffer for color
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_colors);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*3*vertices.size(), &v_color[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Color attribute
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0); //size = 3 (R,G,B)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


//Buffer for normals
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_normals);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*3*vertices.size(), &v_normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//normal attribute
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0); //size = 3 (R,G,B)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


// Unbind the VAO
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

My data are :

```
vector<vec3> vertices, v_normals,v_color;
vector<int> vTable;
```

I have vertices, normals and colors per vertex and an index table with the index vertices of each triangle.

When I try to render this, nothing appears on the window.

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO); //Bind VAO
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vTable.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &vTable[0]);
glBindVertexArray(0); //Unbind VAO
```

If I used this:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,vTable.size());
```

It draws something but an incomplete object, like in the link image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/649XQ.png)

Anybody knows what happens? Thanks in advance

Comment: The last parameter of `glDrawElements` is an offset in the index buffer. So you should pass a null pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **`glDrawElements`** call is wrong, the last parameter should be a byte offset into your `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` that holds the indices, not pointer to system memory.

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vTable.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```